# Ubuntu updated while in Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, updates, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hoping someone can help out.

I am dual booting Windows 10 and the latest Ubuntu distro, I noticed that when in Windows an installer started up and as I clicked on it I could see it was installing Ubuntu software however it disappeared too quick to see what was happening.

Does this happen often, should it be something I worry about and is there a way to completely separate the two systems (which I assumed would already be done due to partitions on my SSD).

I will do my own research, but if anyone has any quick answers, I would appreciate the feedback. Cheers

Comment: When dual booting and within the Windows 10 OS, Windows 10 will in no way interact with Ubuntu under normal circumstances.  Sure, there are plenty of ways for them to communicate, but typically you won't be installing stuff in Ubuntu from Windows OS.

Comment: The only other way that I can think of is if you have the [Subsystem for Linux](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) enabled in Windows 10 that you might see something about Ubuntu software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't install Ubuntu software. This is most certainly **not** something that happens *often*. My experience has been that it happens *never*, and it is impossible as Windows doesn't even recognize Linux file-systems.

The only possibilities that come to my mind is that either:

- You are mistaken
- You've installed [The Ubuntu Userspace for Windows Developers](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2016/03/ubuntu-on-windows.html) and possibly Microsoft released a patch related to that

Note that while The Ubuntu Userspace for Windows can run ELF binaries (or so I've heard) it is **not** Ubuntu.

Comment: You wee genius you. I completely forgot that I installed Bash for Windows as I did it so long ago. I recently set up dual booting so my head went straight to that. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: @FraserBurnett Glad to help. We had [quite the discussion](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15229/do-we-consider-ubuntu-on-windows-10-the-same-as-an-official-ubuntu-flavour-do) here on Meta about that when the news broke. I'm glad you are dual booting now!

Comment: Yeah, trying to force myself across to Linux. Just takes time to get used to it again. Used it a lot at uni (computer systems and networks degree) and after uni moved into a pretty much Windows only environment so lost a lot of the Linux skills I had learnt, which saddens me :(